# How to use Handlebars with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js

I encountered the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'compile' of undefined.
```

RequireJS configuration:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "resources",
    paths: {
        'app':'lib',
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.9.1',
        'bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap',
        'html5shiv': 'lib/html5shiv',
        'spin': 'lib/spin',
        'respond': 'lib/respond',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'handlebars': 'lib/handlebars-v3.0.3',
        'template': 'app/templates'
    },
    shim: {
        html5shiv: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        respond: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        handlebars: {
            exports: "Handlebars"
        }
    }
});

require([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'handlebars',
    'app/Router'
], function($,
            _,
            Backbone,
            Handlebars,
            Router) {
    var router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

View:

```
define([
  'backbone',
  'handlebars',
  'text!templates/mytemplate.html'
], function(Backbone, Handlebars, Template){

    MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    return MyView;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`shim` is for libraries that doesn't support AMD. The version of handlebars you're using probably supports AMD and doesn't define a global variable named `Handlebars`. Hence you get the error. Try removing `handlebars` config from shim.